# How to implement ActiveMQ with VM's using NAS

Tags: c#, .net, vmware, activemq-classic, nas

We're in the process of moving our .NET platform from using MSMQ to ActiveMQ.  We pump 30+ million persistent messages through it a day, so throughput and capacity are critical to us.  The way our MSMQ dependent applications are configured, is they write to local/private queues first.  Then we have a local service that routes those messages to their respective remote queues for processing.  This ensures the initial enqueue/write write is fast (yes, we can also use async enqueueing as well), and messages aren't lost if the remote servers are unavailable.

We were going to use the same paradigm for ActiveMQ, but now we've decided to move to using VM's with NAS storage for most of our application servers.  This greatly reduces the write performance of each message since it's going to NAS, and I feel I need to rethink our approach to queueing.  I'd like to know what is considered best practice for using ActiveMQ, with persistent, high throughput needs.  Should I consider using dedicated queue servers (that aren't VM's)?  But that would mean all writes from the application are going directly over the network.  How do I deal with high availability requirements?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy ActiveMQ instances in a [network of brokers](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) and the topology can include local instances as well as remote instances. I have deployed topologies containing a local instance of ActiveMQ so that messages are persisted as close to the sender as possible and then the messages are forwarded to remote ActiveMQ instances based on demand. With this style of topology, I recommend configuring the network connector(s) to disallow forwarding messages from all destinations. I.e., instead of openly allowing the forwarding of messages for all destinations, you may want to narrow the number of messages forwarded using the excludedDestinations property.

As far as high availability with ActiveMQ, the [master/slave](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html) configuration is designed for exactly this. It comes in three flavors depending on your needs.

Hope that helps.

Bruce